# CPP-REST-SDK in Centos 7

Tags: centos, centos7, cpprest-sdk

I have a CentOS 7 (EPEL-Repo is registered) but I do not find the package for CPP-REST (libcpprest-dev in Debian) in the repos.

Do I need to install it from vanilla or is there a package in CentOS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Short answer...

**There is not an "official" CentOS 7 package at this time (2018-10-03) for cpprestsdk (libcpprest-dev in Debian).**

Long answer (sharing this in case it helps anyone)...

You could build cpprestsdk from source, but the instructions "How to build for Linux" (https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/How-to-build-for-Linux) do not include CentOS or RHEL (at the time of this writing, 2018-10-03).

Before building cpprestsdk on CentOS 7, you'll need to update boost (at time of this writing CentOS 7 repos have boost 1.53, but 1.54 is required, and 1.68 is latest). You can do this to update (using boost 1.68 as example):

```
cd && wget https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.68.0/source/boost_1_68_0.tar.gz
tar -xzvf boost_1_68_0.tar.gz
cd ~/boost_1_68_0
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/opt/boost
sudo ./b2 install --prefix=/opt/boost --with=all
```

After updating boost, I was able to build cpprestsdk on CentOS 7 like this...

Install some needed tools/libraries:

```
sudo yum -y install git cmake3 openssl-devel gcc-c++ make
```

Download the cpprestsdk project:

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk.git casablanca
```

cpprestsdk wants to treat warnings as errors. I had to turn this off by commenting out this line in ~/casablanca/Release/CMakeLists.txt:

```
#set(WERROR ON CACHE BOOL "Treat Warnings as Errors.")
```

Prepare/build cpprestsdk project:

```
cd casablanca/Release
mkdir build.release && cd build.release
cmake3 .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBOOST_ROOT=/opt/boost
make
```

Install header files and library

```
sudo make install
```

Notice that I am calling cmake3 (not cmake) and I am specifying the boost root; which differs from the official instructions that appear to be written and tested for Ubuntu (not CentOS or RHEL). To build my projects using cpprestsdk, I had to use ldconfig to find the library paths.

Comment: You shouldn't need `boost-devel` since you're using Boost 1.68.0

Comment: Thanks. I removed the boost-devel package from the yum install command.

Comment: Please also not that cpprestsdk fails to build with GCC-9 at this time (https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/issues/1099)

Comment: It worked on RHEL/CentOs 8 as well but You have to Build OpenSSL (https://github.com/openssl/openssl#build-and-install) and install some dependencies like    perl-Pod-Html-1.22.02-416.el8.noarch.rpm,    perl-Test-Simple-1.302135-1.el8.noarch.rpm,    perl-Test-Harness-3.42-1.el8.noarch.rpm.